# MySQL Group By or Order By

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a mysql table

```
C1 - C2
A - 25.6
B - 22.5
C - 19.5
E - 15.6
A - 18.5
B - 20.5
F - 18.2
D - 19.6
F - 16.1
E - 20.6
```

And I need to order DESC c2, without repeating c1

```
A - 25.6
B - 22.5
E - 20.6
D - 19.6
F - 18.2
```

I have so far

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date='$SL_DATE' ORDER BY c2 DESC LIMIT $i",$db);
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         $c2_[$i] = $row[c2];
     }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will work:

```
SELECT C1, max(C2) as maxC2 FROM myTable WHERE date='$SL_DATE' group by C1 order by maxC2 DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the highest `c2` for every `c1`:

```
SELECT c1, max(c2) as max_c2
FROM myTable 
group by c1
order by max_c2 desc
```

Comment: for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT c1, MAX(c2) AS TMP FROM myTable WHERE  GROUP BY c1 LIMIT $i",$db)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C1, MAX(C2) AS C2
FROM myTable
GROUP BY C1
ORDER BY C2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you mean by "not repeating" the first column.  You do want a `group by`.  Here it chooses the max value from the second column:

```
SELECT c1, max(c2)
FROM myTable
group by col1
WHERE date='$SL_DATE
ORDER BY max(c2) DESC
LIMIT $i
```

The following syntax *does* work in MySQL:

```
SELECT c1, c2
FROM myTable
group by col1
WHERE date='$SL_DATE
ORDER BY c2 DESC
LIMIT $i
```

However, it chooses an arbitrary value for `c2` from one of the rows.  You should be more specific about which value you want -- such as the largest value.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I need the largest value from c2, while not including more than once c1

Answer (score 0):

1. Don 't use the PHP mysql_* extension anymore. In the latest Version of PHP the mysql_* extension is marked as deprecated.
2. In my eyes you can 't reach your goal just with MySQL. YOu have to use php to manage the groups. Just like the following example done with the PHP PDO Object you should use in the future.

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY column1";
   try {
       foreach ($db->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
           if (!isset($data[$row['column1'])) {
               $data[$row['column1'] = array();
           }

           $data[$row['column1'][] = $row['column2'];
       }
   } catch (PDOExcpetion $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       exit;
   }

   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($data);
   echo "</pre>";
   ```

In die data Array there are groups as keys, that only appear once. In these groups all values are given.